# How to bind gridview to allow paging when datasource is Datatable generated by cloning in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="InGridView" PageSize="5" AllowPaging="true"  runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="InGridView_PageIndexChanging" ></asp:GridView>
```

code binding to grid.

```
private void LoadGridView(string filename)
{
    invTable = new DataTable();
   // gets data from uploaded csv file
  DataTable csvDatatable=GetdataFromCSV(string filename)
    // Code to populate invTable with the data..
    invTable= checkCsvandGetTable(csvDatatable)
    InGridView.DataSouce = invTable;
    inGridView.DataBind();
```

}
where data binding is being done on button_click and datasource is datatable which i am generating from csv file.

how to allow paging in such scenario

```
the invTable is null when i am selecting 2 page for first page its working fine.
```

any idea on this?

Comment: can you share the code of how you populate `invTable` and how are you binding GridView to the table ? One thing you need to understand is ASP.NET is stateless.. Entire page life cycle gets executed everytime when page is posted back. so if you have initialized the table in button_click it's value will not be persisted in Postback or page refresh.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yep, i have initialized table at button click.any idea how can we achieve this functionality then?

Comment: You need to initialize the table again and populate it with the paged data and bind it to the gridview in InGridView_PageIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load `invTable` with the data again and bind it to the GridView in PageIndexChanged event.

Let say you have a method which creates a datatable, populates it with data and binds it to the gridview. And you are calling this method from the button click.

```
private void LoadGridView()
{
    invTable = new DataTable();
    // Code to populate invTable with the data..
    InGridView.DataSouce = invTable;
    inGridView.DataBind();
}
```

You need to call the same method from the `PageIndexChanged` event handler.
So, `PageIndexChanged` eventhandler of InGridView should be written as following.

```
protected void InGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    InGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    LoadGridView();
}
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: actually the invTable  is getting created dynamically and when page loads it gets disposed ,so this method wont help.is there is a way where we can cach the table?

Comment: That's why you need to call LoadGridView method which takes care of creating the table and populating it with the data. Did you try this code? I would suggest to try this code before making any conclusions.

Comment: yep, i tried it. actually the code where invTable gets populated is a method ,which has 40 condition to check.on successful filtration its gets data back a table from the method. i have updated my code ,you can check.

Comment: What happens when you use this code? It is not doing pagination? Any Error?